# IOS/Xcode: Coredata:property name private appears red in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an attribute in a number of my core data entities by the name of private.  It is a boolean.

In the NSObject for the entity, the word private appears in red as opposed to black text.  None of the other attribute names are in red and, when I use a name that is a known reserved term such as "description" it is black--although Apple warns against using "description" as an attribute name.

Here is how the property appears in the object file.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *private;//bool
```

Of note, `@property (nonatomic, strong)` is always red in Xcode.

The private attribute seems to hold values fine.  For example, I can store a value in it and retrieve it.  However, my NSPredicate filters against the word property are not working properly which is why I have focused in on this oddity.

Incidentally the name private is red in multiple entities and if I take away a letter and make it "privat" for example, it is again black.

Does anyone know what red means, whether private is some kind of reserved term and/or whether the red means anything?

Answer (score 1):

It's a reserved keyword in C++ which Xcode colors the same color as other reserved keywords in header files.

It isn't reserved in ObjC so it should be fine to use if the syntax highlighting doesn't bother you.

`description` isn't a reserved keyword, it just isn't allowed to be used as a Core Data attribute name because its accessor would have the same signature as the `description` method that is inherited from `NSObject`.